# the print of getAbsolutePath in Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea

My development environment: Mac + IntelliJ Idea.

I'm practicing the File class in Java.

```
public class FileDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("/Users/Samuel/IdeaProjects/JavaFundamentals/src/aa/bb/test.txt");
        file.createNewFile();
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }

}
```

the result is `/Users/Samuel/IdeaProjects/JavaFundamentals/src/aa/bb/test.txt`

It's OK.But after I changed the path,the print became strange.

```
public class FileDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("test.txt"); //notice this line
        file.createNewFile();
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }

}
```

the print is `/Users/Samuel/IdeaProjects/test.txt`

I'm confused of the path.

Answer (score 1):

Because `"test.txt"` is a relative path and the file will be created relative to the program's working directory (in this case `/Users/Samuel/IdeaProjects/`).

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you have provided the `full path` in your initialization. So it is printing the full path. In the second case, you are using `relative paths`. The base path for that is home directory of your project.

Comment: I know AbsolutePath and RelativePath.For mac,The second program above prints `/Users/Samuel/IdeaProjects/test.txt`.For windows,it will print `/Users/Samuel/IdeaProjects/JavaFundamentals/src/aa/bb/test.txt`.What confused me is the difference.Is it caused by the difference of system?

Comment: Please check the Java Documentation for [File.getAbsolutePath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath--). **On UNIX systems, a relative pathname is made absolute by resolving it against the current user directory. On Microsoft Windows systems, a relative pathname is made absolute by resolving it against the current directory of the drive named by the pathname, if any; if not, it is resolved against the current user directory.**

Answer (score 0):

1) When you provide the full path in File class constructor while creating the File object then it will create the file on mentioned path.

2) But In case you are not providing the full path then it will create the File on the same path where your .class file is. It is relative path.

Answer (score 0):

Your project folder is the main folder for the File class. This is where the File class starts from. If you want a lower folder you need te specify your path or you can use: "new File("../");
The main reason why it is in the folder "IdealProjects" is, because this is the start path of your project.